# how to create 2nd view in/over mtkview

Tags: macos, metal

I'am learning Swift, Metal/MetalKit to create an engineering app. I don't use Interface Builder because of poor eyesight (I get lost in xcode).
running OSX 10.11 on 27" iMac.

I have a running mtkview displaying 3D graphics, but need to add another view on top (in corner) to show the view orientation.

I had a second opengl view for this in Linux, gtkmm, and mesa 3d, but I can't find any documentation on how to add a second view in metal.

I tried adding a second mtkview to my program, but nothing happens (I don't think it's recognized).

What's the best way to do this?

1. add a 2nd mtkview on top of the existing view? (if so, how)
2. render the 2nd view as pert of the existing view render process?
3. some other method?

Does anyone have any info or example of how to do this?

Comment: Can you share the code you use to create and add the second view? As always, you'll need to explicitly set the frame of the view and add it either as a subview or sibling view of the primary view. I would expect `MTKView`s to composite together exactly as generic `NSView`s do. If the second view isn't showing up, you should be able to inspect the view hierarchy and the views' properties in the debugger.

Comment: Hi I edited your question a bit so the list at the end is properly displayed, and some of your phrases start at a new paragraph.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. It took me a while to clean up my code so it wouldn't confuse the issue. My code is based on a tutorial by Marius (thanks! Marius). and I've been playing around with it.

Comment: Hi, as you might have noticed, I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to get my code to you... I'm still working on it. please be patient....

Comment: Hi again, I didn't figure out how to share my code, but I have a link to the tutorial code I based it on: [link]https://github.com/Swiftor/Metal/commit/05c96f48a9cb4d1ba6f34a99c3f3808822fc200a

Answer (score 3):

There's a really easy answer to this. Metal uses the so called view port to specify what part of the view should be drawn. Everything out of the view port is left as is. This is how you can use it:

```
// Draw the full view here

let topLeft = MTLViewport(originX: 10, 
                          originY: 10, 
                          width: size.width / 3, 
                          height: size.height / 3, 
                          znear: 0, 
                          zfar: 1)

renderEncoder.setViewport(topLeft)

// Draw the top left view here
```

Of course you shouldn't always calculate the `topLeft` view port, as it only changes when the view size changes and therefore put it in the `mtkView:drawableSizeWillChange:` method.